# HTML and CSS (navigation bar)

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

How do I enter the following code into CSS so that I don't have to copy and paste it in every HTML page?

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

My issue is especially with the "ul" and "li" -I am not sure what to do with this!  Any help would be greatly appreciated- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the html in a seperate .CSS stylesheet and reference it as:

```
<link href="url to stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

To use the ul and li tags you would write something similar to this:

```
<ul>

<li>
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul>
```

Comment: I have already created a style sheet. My issue is with how I would input the code into it. For instance, would I need to create tags for <div id=" "> or <ul id=" "> and, if so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: you would do <ul id ="">

Answer (score 2):

Place your css in a separate file and use the following directive to make it accessible in each page:

```
<link href="url to stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) file and link it to your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Add your css in separate `.css` file and call it in html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```